# Linq: Is there a way to search a list of list of objects for values that match a condition?

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 types of objects, TypeA,TypeB,TypeC. TypeA has a list of TypeB and TypeB has a list of TypeC, and TypeC has some variables I wanna keep track of

```
Class TypeA
{
  List<TypeB> MyListOfTypeB;
  //...
}

Class TypeB
{
  List<TypeC> MyListOfTypeC;
  //...
}

Class TypeC
{
  int SomeInteger;
  //...
}
```

Given a `List<TypeA> MyListOfTypeA`, I wanna look for all TypeC Objects which fulfill a certain condition, such as, SomeInteger > 100. Other than nesting for/foreach loops, what is the Linq way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var MyListOfTypeA = new List<TypeA>();
// ...
var cItems = 
    from a in MyListOfTypeA
    from b in a.MyListOfTypeB
    from c in a.MyListOfTypeC
    where c.SomeInteger > 100
    select c;
```

The above is equivalent to calling the `SelectMany` LINQ function, but in my opinion it is significantly cleaner and easier to read.

Doing it with LINQ functions (as already suggested by Dmitry, though with some modifications):

```
var cItems = 
    MyListOfTypeA.SelectMany( a => a.MyListOfTypeB )
                 .SelectMany( b => b.MyListOfTypeC )
                 .Where( c => c.SomeValue > 200 );
```

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent, but in my experience, when the query becomes more and more complicated, it is easier for me to clearly see the scope of each statement when using Lambdas in the Linq's extention methods. But I can only offer this as a personal opinion and preference. Also, the query syntax is later converted into the extention methods I used anyway during compilation i believe, I like dealing with the actual methods that are being called rather then with a simplified syntactic sugar abstration that at times gets confusing because it looks like SQL but is not. Sorry for the rant.

Comment: @Dmitry - I totally agree. If the query were more complex, I'd probably rewrite it as a series of LINQ functions. I use whatever is clearer in the given situation.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this is what you're looking for i think:

```
var result = MyListOfTypeA.SelectMany(b => b.MyListOfTypeB.SelectMany(c => c.MyListOfTypeC.Select(x => x.SomeInteger > 100))).ToList();
```

Comment: Actually, I believe that that would be a plain `Select()` for the first 2 types.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it would be more like this: `var result = MyListOfTypeA.SelectMany(b => b.MyListOfTypeB).SelectMany(c => c.MyListOfTypeC).Select(x => x.SomeInteger > 100).ToList();`
But I can't test right now.

Comment: That said, the linq syntax proposed by @Cyborgx37 looks much cleaner in that case...

Comment: @Johnny5 no, I'm pretty sure that the nesting of the statements is correct in my answer, but I can't test it either right now.

Comment: @Johnny5 - The results are the same, actually. Although I think `MyListOfTypeC.SelectMany(x => x.SomeInteger > 100)` was supposed to be `MyListOfTypeC.Where(x => x.SomeInteger > 100)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the following way using Linq:

```
    var myListOfTypeA = new List<TypeA>();

    // fill your list here

    var typeCs = from typeA in myListOfTypeA
                 from typeB in typeA.MyListOfTypeB
                 from typeC in typeB.MyListOfTypeC
                 where typeC.SomeInteger > 100
                 select typeC;
```

Comment: But in the original scenario, MyListOfTypeA doesn't have any objects of TypeC. It only contains objects of type A, each of which has a list of "B"s, each of which has a list of "C"s.

Answer (score 2):

You need to navigate all sublists, and that what `from` can do for you.

```
var ta = new TypeA();

var allTypeCsThatSatisfyMyCondition = 
    from tb in ta.MyListOfTypeB                     // This will iterate to each item in the list
    from tc in tb.MyListOfTypeC                     // This will iterate to each item in the *sublist*
    where tc.SomeInteger > 100          // Condition could be anything; filter the results
    select tc;                                      // When you select, you tell your iterator to yield return that value to the caller.

return allTypeCsThatSatisfyMyCondition.ToList();    // To list will force the LINQ to execute and iterate over all items in the lists, and add then to a list, effectively converting the returned items to a list.
```